# how to search/replace Ansible regex using replace module

Tags: regex, ansible

I wanted to search and replace "GATEWAY=192.168.0.253" in ansible plabook.
I've below code but string is not getting replaced. I am not good with 
Any help will be appreciated to match the string end of the line.

```
 tasks:
    - name: "Homenet GateWay Change"
      replace:
        dest: /opt/ifcfg-br0
        regexp: '^(GATEWAY=)\s*$'
        replace: 'GATEWAY=192.168.0.1'
        backup: yes
      when: HOMENET
    - name: "Hoemnet DNS Change"
      replace:
        dest: /opt/ifcfg-br0
        regexp: '^(DNS1=)\s*$'
        replace: 'DNS1=192.168.0.1'
        backup: yes
      when: HOMENET
    - service: name=network state=restarted
```

Comment: Try `'GATEWAY=[0-9.]+'` regex.

Comment: Take some time and construct valid regexp with https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for any IP address, you can use this regex:

```
GATEWAY=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

Or if you are not looking for valid IP's you can also just use this regex:

```
GATEWAY=[0-9\.]+
```

And replace it with

```
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
```

---

Here is a running example:

```js
var text = "This is a GATEWAY=192.168.0.3 and this is also a GATEWAY=192.168.0.8";
var regex = /GATEWAY=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/g
var replacement = "GATEWAY=192.168.0.1";

var result = text.replace(regex, replacement);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response

Comment: Does this help you? You can upvote and accept (✔ on the left side) the question if you like to.